# WPF Access Label from class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Service.cs**

```
public class Service
{
    private Timer timer;
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;

    public Service()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 60000;
        timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(OnTick);
        // ...
    }

    public void StartTimer() { /* ... */ }

    public void PauseTimer() { /* ... */ }

    private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (minutes == 59) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours += 1;
        } else {
            minutes += 1;
        }

        //...

        // NOW I WANT TO SET THE CONTENT OF servicePage.hoursl AND servicePage.minutesl
        // ACCORDING TO THE VALUES I GET ON this.hours AND this.minutes
    }
```

**servicePage.xaml**

```
<Label x:Name="hoursl" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<Label x:Name="minutesl" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

**servicePage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class servicePage : Page { /* ... */ }
```

I have a class called Service in which I need to have a Timer for each instance of Service.
Then I have a page with 2 labels, 1 for the hours (hoursl) and 1 for the minutes (minutesl).

Is there a way to access the labels from servicePage on the function OnTick()?
And set those labels' contents to the values of the hours and minutes provided by the timer?

Comment: You must pass the reference to the `ServicePage` instance when you create the instance of your `Service`.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into the MVVM pattern instead of using code-behind to replicate what the WPF Binding Engine already provides.

Comment: The problem is all instances of `Service` are created on `Application_Startup` and the `servicePage` is not yet `Loaded`.

Comment: A Service class would not ordinarily be concerned with updating the UI controls, but the publish/subscribe pattern could work well for you.  You can set up your Service class as an IObservable to which any of your pages can subscribe when they are constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ServicePage needs to subscribe to an event published by your Service class. This way it will know when the timer ticks.

Then you can update the two labels appropriately.

If using MVVM, your view model would subscribe to the event and via binding update the labels in the view.

Here's a simple non MVVM example:

```
public class Service
{
    public delegate void TimerTickHandler(int hours, int minutes);
    public event TimerTickHandler TimerTick;
    .
    .
    .

    private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ...

      if (TimerTick != null)
           TimerTick(hours, minutes);


    }
}
```

Now your ServicePage class would need an instance of that Service class and subscribe to the event.  A similar approach would be done if you went the MVVM route.

If your Service class is instantiated on Application_Startup only, if it makes sense, you could follow the singleton pattern to store the instance so other classes can get the instance.  That would only work if you could only have one instance of the timer per application.

Singleton: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Once the Service class is a singleton, the ServicePage.xaml.cs can get the public instance and subscribe to the TimerTick event.

Hope this helps.